# Fantasy book about bedtime stories that become true the next day

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book about 5 years ago. The story from what I can remember goes like this:

- The main character is a kid. and his mom reads him a bedtime story about a dead bull with its eye out (I might be wrong about the specific details).
- The next day the kid walks to school. he goes into the woods and sees a dead bull with its eye missing.
- The mom continues the bedtime story the next night, and it becomes true the next morning (I don't remember what the rest of the bedtime story was).
- In the third act, there is a big fight in the city and something is chasing the kid and his family (I think the thing chasing them is a large eye but I'm not sure).
- I'm pretty sure the main character has a brother.

Comment: Is this a YA novel? A middle grade book? Something else?

Comment: @Mithical- probably a middle grade book